# Join 3 tables and get a sum of product stock postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

**Categories** table

| category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | kitchen |
| 2 | bedroom |

**Suppliers** table

| supplier_id | supplier_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | amazon |
| 2 | wallmart |
| 2 | ebay |

**Product** table

| product_id | product_name | category_id | supplier_id | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bed | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | table | 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | glass | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | plate | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 5 | spoon | 1 | 3 | 20 |

I want current state of suppliers stocks for each category of product.

Expected result:

| CATEGORY | suppliers | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bedroom | amazon | 2 |
| kitchen | amazon | 4 |
| bedroom | wallmart | 10 |
| kitchen | ebay | 30 |

Comment: Please share what SELECT queries you've tried.

Comment: Join your tables `FROM product INNER JOIN suppliers on product.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id INNER JOIN categories ON product.category_id = categories.category_id` SELECT what you need `SELECT category.category_name, suppliers.supplier_name, sum(product.stock)` and group by your first two columns `GROUP BY category_name, supplier_name`. Should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.category_name,S.supplier_name,SUM(P.stock)TOTAL_STOCK
FROM PRODUCT P
JOIN Categories C ON P.category_id=C.category_id
JOIN Suppliers S ON P.supplier_id=S.supplier_id
GROUP BY C.category_name,S.supplier_name
```

You can try something like this

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SwTHkYnn)

Answer (score 0):

```
select   category_name as category
        ,supplier_name as suppliers
        ,sum(stock)    as stock
from     product p join suppliers s using(supplier_id) join categories using(category_id)
group by category_name, supplier_name
```

| category | suppliers | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bedroom | amazon | 2 |
| bedroom | ebay | 10 |
| bedroom | wallmart | 10 |
| kitchen | amazon | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fpnjKrgC)